# How do you recurse if statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion

Im trying to make a category system with parents. Here is how my database is structured.
- id
- name
- parent_id

Basically what I want it to do is check if there is a parent id, and if so then check if the parent id, and if that parent has a parent id, and so on. Then output the parents in order until it reached the child.

Currently what I am doing (in Ruby/Ruby on Rails) is this:

```
<% @cat = Category.find_by_id(@project.category) %>
<% if @cat.parent_id.nil? %>
    <%= @cat %>
<% else %>
  <%= Category.find_by_id(@cat.parent_id).name%> => <%= @cat.name %>
<% end %>
```

The problem with this is that it only gets one parent. I need it to recurse and constantly gather the parent until it hits and end, **and also I dont want it to take up too much memory**. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: Ok,.. write a helper method...

Comment: If you use the [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem, you get a ton of helper methods for finding parents, ancestors, children, etc.

Comment: @jstim It is very easy.. to write by one.. so I think no need to get a gem.. But its a choice of individual..

Comment: @ArupRakshit Can you please give an example?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I agree. It sounded to me like the OP is trying to build a breadcrumb, and is hand-writing an arbitrarily-deeply nested category system. There are a few libraries that provide some nice helpers for managing those relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a method on your model to search for the parent

```
class Category
  # inline, less memory usage 
  def last_parent
    last = self
    while last.parent
      last = last.parent  
    end
    last
  end

  # recursive, better readability
  def last_parent_recursive
    if parent
      parent.last_parent_recursive
    else
      self
    end
  end
end
```

then, on your view:

```
<%= @cat.last_parent %>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Quick question: Why is it that the sub categories have a `--` even though its not in the code?

Comment: @nahtnam sorry, didn't got your question :(

Comment: @nahtnam if you try to explain better I might be able to help.

Comment: Sorry, wrong question. For some reason my code changed permissions and the site wont update. I will get back to you later.

Comment: I am getting this error: `undefined method `last_parent' for #<Category id: 18, name: "Online", parent_id: 17>`. Here is the extracted source: https://gist.github.com/nahtnam/c6a40a97b1de54d82df5 Line number 4 is highlighted.

Comment: @nahtnam The view is fine, but the last_parent. It seems to me that the `last_parent` method is not defined inside the `Category` model (assuming it is a model from ruby on rails). If you still don't know how to solve, let me see the category model (assuming rails, `app/models/category.rb`) - feel free to edit your question and ping me

Comment: How can I associate two models together? I need to display the categories in the projects model. I have the view setup in /projects/view/ and I put the code in the model.

Comment: I have a projects model/controller/view that I am using and I need to list out all of the categories there.

Comment: @nahtnam My answer assumes that a Category `belongs_to :parent, class_name:"Category"`, but you might have to specify `foreign_key` as well. Check this [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association). Other than that, how to create the association would be another question - suggest you to minimize the question the most you can in complexity, and then post other question here.

Comment: This is what I have at the top of my categories model. https://gist.github.com/nahtnam/298c48d5ff8b4c13f8dd